# how I modify my id null to not null in sql

Tags: mysql

```
ALTER TABLE temp_db.product MODIFY id INT NOT NULL;
```

> #1265 - Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1

i think this is the correct way to change the property null to not null

Answer (score 0):

Your `ALTER` syntax is fine, but to get rid of the error message, you need to first update the `NULL` values in the `id` column to some non `NULL` value:

```sql
UPDATE temp_db.product
SET id = <something other than NULL>
WHERE id IS NULL;
```